# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 shows "var" instead of actual type

Tags: intellij-idea

After upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 variables now do not show their types. Instead, it shows `var`. Also, it abbreviates some method calls. For example instead `me.getIdAsStr()` it shows `me.idAsStr`. How to revert to the old behavior?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you use [Advanced Java Folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9320-advanced-java-folding) plug-in?

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, but it was not causing such behaviour prior to 2017.1. Did they change this now or?

Comment: So, disable plug-in if you don't like the features it provides or configure the plug-in according to your needs.

Comment: @CrazyCoder add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the [Advanced Java Folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9320-advanced-java-folding) plug-in. Either disable the plug-in or change its setting to not fold certain code elements.

Answer (score 13):

To disable showing `val`/`var` instead of variable type
go to **Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding** 
and *UnCheck* **Variable Declaration**

And just next to it
*Uncheck* **Getters and setters**
to start showing getter Setter method calls with full method name

[image]