# Disable "code hiding feature" in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

**Remark: This question is (up to now) not a duplicate. I know how to disable the hints. This is not what I am looking for.**

In intelliJ a feature "hides" parts of my code, e.g. variable declarations as "var" or getter methods like in the example below.

The code shows `t.message`, but the code behind this visual abbrevation is `t.getMessage()`. How can I disable that feature and always show `t.getMessage()`?

Abbreviated code:

[image]

Real code:

[image]

Because I don't know the name of the feature I have no idea what I am looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: This feature is provided by a plugin which you have installed (Advanced Code Folding). You can disable the plugin in Settings | Plugins or configure it in Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding.

Comment: Ah man, I was so desperately searching in the settings... Thanks for the help, that did the trick! (detail: the plugin I installed was called Advanced Java Folding)

Answer (score 0):

To disable showing `val`/`var` instead of variable type
go to **Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding** 
and *UnCheck* **Variable Declaration**

And just next to it
*Uncheck* **Getters and setters**
to start showing getter Setter method calls with full method name

refer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271952/3661654
[image]