# Why my java code looks like Kotlin in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I create a new android project in android studio 3.3 in JAVA 
when I open a java file, all the code collapsed like the Kotlin code,
it is expanded when I click on each line 
Hot prevent that 
see the screenshot bellow

[image]

Comment: Looks like the Advanced Java Folding plugin, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975239/4465208